# Mostrar datos en detalles

Tags: django

He creado un formulario en Django pero cuando quiero mostrar los detalles de un registro no me trae la fecha de actualización, quisiera ver por qué no me trae ese dato.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models


class Empleados(models.Model):

    OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Femenino'),
    )

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ci = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    documento = models.FileField(
        upload_to="archivo/",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.nombre

class ActualizacionEmpleado(models.Model):
    empleado = models.ForeignKey('Empleados', null = False, blank = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fecha_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.empleado
```

**detalles.html**:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block Contenido %}

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col.lg-3">
        <h4>Registro ID #: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.id }}</p></ul>            
        <h4>Nombre: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.nombre }}</p></ul>            
        <h4>Apellidos: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.apellidos }}</p></ul>            
        <h4>Cedula de identidad: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.ci }}</p></ul>
        <h4>Genero: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.genero }}</p></ul>         
        <h4>Fecha de ingreso: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.creado }}</p></ul>            
        <h4>Email: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.email }}</p></ul>            
        <h4>Telefono: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.telefono }}</p></ul>            
        <h4>Documento: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.documento }}</p></ul>
        <h4>Ultima actualizacion: </h4>
            <ul><p>{{ object.actualizacionempleado.fecha_actualizacion }}</p></ul>            
    </div>
</div>
<center>
    <FORM name="buttonbar">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Regresar" onClick="history.back()">
    </FORM>
</center>
<center>
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="imprimir" onclick="javascript:window.print()"> 
</center>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

¿Qué me falta?, ya que cuando hago llamado a detalles me trae todo los datos solicitados menos el de fecha de actualización.

Answer (score 1):

Es por la forma en que tienes relacionados los modelos.

Si le dices a tu base de datos que en la tabla `ActualizacionEmpleado` cree una llave foránea (`ForeignKey`) a la tabla `Empleados`. Lo que se hará es que se creará una relación de uno a muchos:

```
ActualizacionEmpleado * => 1 Empleados
```

Por lo que visto de tu tabla de `Empleados` tienes es la relación inversa, es decir de muchos a uno:

```
Empleados 1 => * ActualizacionEmpleado
```

Dicho de otra forma, tu empleado puede tener muchas actualizaciones (pero en modelos), y tus actualizaciones solo pertenecen a un empleado.

Entonces, dicho lo anterior si tu ejecutas la siguiente cláusula: `object.actualizacionempleado.fecha_actualizacion`, sabiendo que `object` es una instancia de `Empleados`, entonces, según lo anterior, Django no sabrá como resolver eso ya que un empleado tiene muchas actualizaciones, entonces, ¿Cuál actualización debería mostrar?

Algo a tener en cuenta, esa relación inversa o relativa, se le es asignado un nombre automático si tu no lo determinas mediante el parámetro `related_field` cuando defines el campo en el modelo. Y por defecto para tu caso sería `actualizacionempleado_set`. Con esto, lo correcto sería hacer esto:

```
object.actualizacionempleado_set.all()
```

Si lo ves así, en realidad es un `QuerySet` como si hiciera una consulta así: `ActualizacionEmpleado.objects.filter(empleado=object)`

Para ayudarte un poco más con tu problema, quizá esta no es la relación que necesitas si no una de *Uno a Uno*

Pero si quieres seguir por este camino, algo así te serviría para por lo menos mostrar algo, te recomendaría ordenar para asegurarte de tener el dato mas actualizado: `{{ object.actualizacionempleado_set.all.0.fecha_actualizacion }}` desde el template de Django eso debería mostrarte algo siempre y cuando tengas datos en la base de datos

Comment: Gracias por tu explicacion, probe lo que me sugeriste pero no me funciono, incluso revise la base de datos y no me esta capturando nada

Comment: @JhonnyBarreto edita tu pregunta con la nueva información que tienes para poder seguir ayudandote

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que quieres mostrar la última fecha de actualización de un empleado, primero debes realizar la búsqueda en tu vista:

```
actualizacion_empleado = ActualizacionEmpleado.objects().filter(empleado=object).last()
```

Pasas la variable `actualizacion_empleado` a la plantilla y
el cambio requerido para mostrar la fecha sería el siguiente:

```
<ul><p>{{ actualizacion_empleado.fecha_actualizacion }}</p></ul>
```

Si tu intención es mantener un registro de las fechas en las que se actualiza el perfil de un empleado está bien la forma en que planteas tus modelos, sin embargo, considera la opción `auto_now=True` si requieres guardar únicamente la última fecha de modificación del perfil. Tu modelo quedaría:

```
class Empleados(models.Model):

    OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Femenino'),
    )

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ci = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    actualizado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    documento = models.FileField(
        upload_to="archivo/",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.nombre
```

Así, cada que edites la información del perfil del empleado se guardará la fecha en que fue actualizado, y en tu plantilla ya podrás hacer lo siguiente para mostrarlo:

```
<ul><p>{{ object.actualizado}}</p></ul>
```